# Turning down a MSCA Fellowship due to personal circumstances?

Tags: united-states, postdocs, etiquette, funding, united-kingdom

I am a early career researcher with less than 5 years of postdoc experience since my PhD. After a few years of chaining up short term postdocs I've finally been successfully awarded an MSCA global fellowship to go to the US for two years, with a 1 year return in the UK.

However, life can be tricky and with my partner we've been trying for a family for a long time. About a years and a half ago we decided to stop waiting and get on with our lives. I applied for the fellowship and found myself another 3 year postdoc in a British University ... because, what are the chances of getting a fellowship right? Well it actually happened!

At the same time, after years of waiting, we have reached the top of the IVF waiting list and, if we are lucky, might have a child born a couple of month either side of my, already deferred, fellowship start date in about a year's time.

The fellowship would send me to the San Francisco area, and with the cost of accommodation and health care especially for maternity and new borns the financial picture is really bleak. In fact, to just cover my own living costs, I would have to accept not contributing to my pension for the duration of the fellowship (and neither my employer - as his costs, including his contribution to my pension, is taken from the funding itself.)

Our decision is not made, and so far we are still working towards making that move to the US, but how would one go about turning down the funding once/if the Grant Agreement has been signed between the University and the funder (my own contract wouldn't actually be signed until just before I start as I understand it)?

The award is prestigious, yes, but I'm not sure it is worth putting myself and my partner under a lot of stress and a precarious financial situation with a newborn just for it. I have already told my current employer (as I had disclosed the fellowship application during my interview) that there is a possibility I might be leaving in a year. They have been very supportive and would be happy to keep me on if we decided to not go.

Any advice would be most welcome.

Comment: It is unlikely that you would be the first person to change their mind (for whatever reason). You talk to the grant administrator and see what the options are. If possible, turn it down before any agreements are signed with the university.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a complete answer, but I'll suggest a few things that you should look in to before making a decision.

I don't know what is possible a MSCA fellowship, but if it is possible to delay it for a year (or so) you might have more options.

While not up to UK standards, public transport in the Bay Area is getting better and it is possible to work in SF, but not live there, choosing a more reasonable housing situation in exchange for a commute. You would need to do a geographical search to see what is possible.

Quite a lot of people work remotely out of the Bay Area and live far away, but that probably isn't feasible for some, or desirable for a postdoc.

Explore with the university whether you will have any automatic medical coverage for yourself and partner. Possible, but the external funding might be an issue. Some places might have more flexibility in this than others. For example, Stanford, which is private, might have more leeway than a university in the UC system which is bound by state regulations.

If you need to turn it down, you don't need to say much. "Family requirements won't permit me to accept *at this time*. Thank you ...".

Anyway, congratulations on both the fellowship and the possibility of a child.